# Get the last created thing among siblings in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, unique, distinct

How do you retrieve a list of the newest NODE in a path in neo4j? The DISTINCT operator doesn't seem to do what I want.

There is a structure something like this:

```
(n1) - [reln1 cratedAt:"1" something:"not42"] -> ( target )

(n1) - [reln2 cratedAt:"2" something:"42"] -> ( target )

(n2) - [reln3 cratedAt:"1" something:"not42"] -> ( target )

(n2) - [reln4 cratedAt:"3" something:"42"] -> ( target )

(n2) - [reln5 cratedAt:"2" something:"not42"] -> ( target )
```

The issue is that there are an unknown number of parallel relations (or paths) between n1,n2 and target.

Trying to get the query to RETURN the structures with rel2 and rel4 as follows because createdAt is the latest from n1 and n2 respectively. Query should return:

```
(n2) - [reln4 cratedAt:"3" something:"42"] -> ( target )
(n1) - [reln2 cratedAt:"2" something:"42"] -> ( target )
```

I'm looking for relationships or nodes that are carrying weights symbolized by something:42 in this example. What am I missing? Can't this be done in one query? Would it help if they were nodes instead of relationships?

```
MATCH (node)-[rel]->(target)
RETURN DISTINCT node
ORDER BY rel.createdAt
LIMIT 10
```

To make this work I'd need to first order by createdAt, then pick the latest, then return one per node. How?

EDIT: It seems the answers are valid for this structure when created at on relationship - but I can't figure out how to generalize it to longer paths with the createdAt property on a node in the middle. Tricky problem.

There is hard to generalize structure that looks something like this:

```
(O1:Start)-[]-> (mid1:n1 cratedAt:"1" something:"not42") - [reln1 ] -> ( target )

(O1:Start)-[]-> (mid2:n1 cratedAt:"2" something:"42") - [reln2 ] -> ( target )

(O2:Start)-[]-> (mid3:n2 cratedAt:"1" something:"not42") - [reln3 ] -> ( target )

(O2:Start)-[]-> (mid4:n2 cratedAt:"3" something:"42") - [reln4 ] -> ( target )

(O2:Start)-[]-> (mid5:n2 cratedAt:"2" something:"not42") - [reln5 ] -> ( target )
```

Query should RETURN

```
(O1:Start)-[]-> (mid2:n1 cratedAt:"2" something:"42") - [reln2 ] -> ( target )
(O2:Start)-[]-> (mid4:n2 cratedAt:"3" something:"42") - [reln4 ] -> ( target )
```

What I was going for was that labels n1 and n2 are siblings - not just the rel1 rel2 rel3 etc. Is there a better way to manage duplicates by different sources and then query to find the 'right' one?

Comment: What do you mean " want to return rel2 and rel4 in one"? Is it return rel2 and rel4 in one collection? What is the result you are getting? What is not correct on your result.  Also, please give us your expected/correct result. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Tried clarifying the question. Can't get the query to return the newest createdAt..

Comment: thanks for clarifying the question; pls see my answer below. thanks

Comment: Thank you for the answer, seems I wasn't clear enough. I added a bounty. To get the whole way it needs with max() and rel.something ..

Comment: I've made a mistake in the presentation of the problem.. thinking how to rectify it.

Comment: thank you for the answers. I probably need to remake the question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my answer:

1. First you need to get the createdAt date with the max value
2. Then match all nodes with this max value
3. Finally, return the node that you want

> ```
> MATCH ()-[rel]->()  
> WITH  max( rel.cratedAt ) as max_createdAt  
> MATCH (node)-[r]->(target) WHERE r.createdAt = max_createdAt 
> RETURN node  LIMIT 10
> ```

```
 Result:
 ╒═════════════╕
 │"node"       │
 ╞═════════════╡
 │{"name":"n1"}│
 ├─────────────┤
 │{"name":"n2"}│
 └─────────────┘
```

EDITED:  Based on the user comment, I updated the answer below.

> I'm looking to return the whole structure.

```
 MATCH ()-[rel]->()  
 WITH  max( rel.cratedAt ) as max_createdAt  
 MATCH path=(node)-[r]->(target) WHERE r.cratedAt = max_createdAt 
 RETURN path, type(r) as relationship_name
 LIMIT 10

Result:
 ╒═══════════════════════════════════╤═══════════════════╕
 │"path"                             │"relationship_name"│
 ╞═══════════════════════════════════╪═══════════════════╡
 │[{"name":"n1"},{"cratedAt":"2"},{}]│"reln2"            │
 ├───────────────────────────────────┼───────────────────┤
 │[{"name":"n2"},{"cratedAt":"2"},{}]│"reln4"            │
 └───────────────────────────────────┴───────────────────┘
```

Comment: Better. Need to return the relationship as the meaningful part is on there. I should clarify that important info is kept on the relationship which is why I'm looking to return the whole structure. (n2) - [reln4 cratedAt:"2" something:"42"] -> ( target )

Comment: I updated my answer. Please let me get your upvote.

Comment: can't get this to work.. thank you very much for helping me in the right direction.

Comment: what is the issue/error you are getting? we can fix it together! don't give up

Comment: trying generalize to a trickier structure

Comment: I'd need to get the max() for each middle node. apologies for the not generalized question. Looking at FOREACH but that doesn't seem right either. I'm leaning towards getting the whole tree and shaking it out in server code - but that seems less than optimal.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do on this one is perform your MATCH, then ORDER BY the rel's createdAt property, and then collect() the relationships according to the node and target (so per node and target, you'll get the ordered list of relationships), then take the head() of the list (the latest created rel between them).

You really should be using labels, but for now I'll just expand off of your Cypher:

```
MATCH (node)-[rel]->(target)
WITH node, rel, target
ORDER BY rel.createdAt
WITH node, target, collect(rel) as rels
RETURN node, target, head(rels) as rel
LIMIT 10
```

If using Neo4j 4.1.x or later, then you can use a subquery to constrain the expansion and aggregation per node instead of having to do one large aggregation. This will be easier on your heap and thus better as your graph grows:

```
MATCH (node)
CALL {
 WITH node
 MATCH (node)-[rel]->(target)
 WITH rel, target
 ORDER BY rel.createdAt
 WITH target, collect(rel) as rels
 RETURN target, head(rels) as rel
}
RETURN node, target, rel
LIMIT 10
```

(and again, you should be using labels and rel types, otherwise this has to do an AllNodesScan, which will have terrible performance as your graph grows).

Comment: Thank you! this seems to work great and return the newest siblings. Using labels is important and I think I know what you mean. Would an all nodes scan be avoided by somethings like this in the outer scope? I could update your answer if you agree.  MATCH (node)-[rel]->(target {_id:"1234")

Comment: No, you're not using labels there. Labels are prefixed by `:`, and that's missing here. `node`, `rel`, and `target` are all variables here, not label or types.